# How do I do a CTE query in activejdbc?

Tags: postgresql, activejdbc

I need to do a Common Table Expression (CTE) query, but can't figure out how to do this in activejdbc. DB is postgres 9.5

doing:

```
Model.findbySQL("with cte as (...) select * from cte"
```

gives me the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: query must be 'select' query
>       at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.find(DB.java:463)
>       at org.javalite.activejdbc.LazyList.hydrate(LazyList.java:329)
>       at org.javalite.activejdbc.LazyList.toJson(LazyList.java:245)
>       at com.torfiles.webservice.Endpoints.lambda$search$5(Endpoints.java:91)
>       at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:61)
>       at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
>       at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:126)
>       at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: can you include an entire stack trace? In addition, add what database you use.

Comment: Just added the full activejdbc trace, its postgres 9.5

Comment: Please, provide a full  stack trace, including the underlying exeption

Comment: okay, here's my full stack trace.

Comment: Can you include the version of ActiveJdbc?

Comment: its version 1.4.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed in April 2016: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues/483
Please, upgrade to version 1.4.13 to get passed this.